# Azure Devops pipleline for Maven/Rest Assured project

Tags: maven, azure-devops, continuous-integration, rest-assured

I am new to azure devops. I have created a Rest Assured project using TestNG and Maven Dependencies. I am able to build it successfully on my local as a Maven Project. Can I create a CI\CD pipeline on Azure DevOps instead of creating on Jenkins. My project specifically requires to create Azure pipelines. I have also successfully created and build the Azure pipeline for a simple Maven project but when I try to create for Rest Assured with Maven something fails. is there any specific settings required for Rest Assured or it should be same as any Maven project-

[Build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SultL.png)

Comment: To run the REST Assured tests, use the Maven task.  Point the task to your POM.xml file. This will compile the test code and execute the tests. You can refer to this [blog](https://www.deliveron.com/blog/running-rest-assured-api-tests-vsts-release-management/).

Comment: I had tried to do that and was able to build a simple java class. Only when I build the API tests it gives timeout error. Please refer to the screenshot I have attached earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create azure pipeline for Maven Rest Assured project. We need to select the host as Windows host( if we are working on Windows) and then download and setup the respective agent on our local machine. We can then create the build definition for Maven build using classic editor and select the respective pom.xml